# X and Y as float instead of integers

Tags: java, swing, canvas, game-loop

I decided to start working on a project lately, a small 2D game. I already have some gravity working. I'm starting to get better at java but I had never used the java AWT or anything related to rendering prior to this project and basically here's my problem:

I got a character who's walking at 1 pixel per tick, which is too slow. If I up it to just 2 tick, it's too fast and the character is almost sort of running. I'd like kind of in-between but the problem is that X and Y are stored as `int`, and if I changed them to `float`, i would have to convert them to an `int` with something like (int) which will result in removing the floating numbers.

What I have tried is to update the character's X every 2 ticks instead of 1 tick or making the gameloop go slower but it looks rather choppy instead. If anyone has a good solution to that, please leave a message. Thanks!

Comment: Can you not change what `x` and `y` are stored as to `float` as well?

Comment: Yeah, but like i wrote above, the methods from the AWT uses int in the parameters for x and y coordinates since you can't split a pixel in two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the *View* from the *Model* (and look up MVC pattern!)

Use floating point coordinates in your model, convert them to integer pixels only in the visual display.